# AWS Lambda nodejs function throwing exception to generate html to pdf using html-pdf

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, phantomjs, aws-lambda

We have created `AWS Lambda` function to generate html to pdf dynamically in `nodejs4.3` eun environment using html-pdf library.

That function is working well in workstation. We are getting the below exception when test in `AWS Lambda`.

Error Details:

> {
>         "errorMessage": "spawn /var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe ENOENT",
>         "errorType": "Error",
>         "stackTrace": [
>           "exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)",
>           "Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)",
>           "onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)",
>           "nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:437:9)",
>           "process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:392:17)"
>         ]

Can any one advise me, how to resolve this issue.

Comment: The binary of phantomJS is not found it seems

Comment: Take a look at this example setup - https://github.com/lubos/aws-lambda-wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is raised because you don't have PhantomJS binary

> /var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe

that is supposed to save an HTML page to PDF.

But even if you would have that binary packed with you Lambda function, it still wouldn't work: the *.exe extension clearly suggests it's a Microsoft Windows executable. You will need the Linux version to run in AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You should install "phantomjs-prebuilt" and "html-pdf" packages & deploy on *nix machine